Postgres TestContainer with BIGM
The fallowing container works well without trying to enable pg_bigm
    @Shared
    public static final def POSTGRES_SQL_CONTAINER =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("maruta/postgresql-bigm:12-bigm1.2")
                    .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"))
                    .withReuse(true)
                    .withDatabaseName("conceptlifecycle")
                    .withExposedPorts(5432)
                    .withEnv("POSTGRES_USER", "test")
                    .withEnv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "test")
                    .withEnv("POSTGRES_DB", "test")
                    .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd
                            .withName("concept-lifecycle-graphql-api-postgres")
                            .withHostConfig(
                                    HostConfig.newHostConfig().withPortBindings(PortBinding.parse("5435:5432"))
                            ))

I want to be able to run this without errors CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_bigm
I made it work by using an outdated postgre version maruta/postgresql-bigm:12-bigm1.2
I also made it work using docker-compose support
spring.docker.compose.enabled=true
spring.docker.compose.lifecycle-management=start_and_stop
spring.docker.compose.skip.in-tests=false
spring.docker.compose.file=docker-compose.yml

compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    build: .
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: bigmdemo
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Dockerfile
FROM postgres:15

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        postgresql-server-dev-15 \
        git \
        make \
        gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Clone and install pg_bigm
RUN git clone https://github.com/pgbigm/pg_bigm.git \
    && cd pg_bigm \
    && make USE_PGXS=1 \
    && make USE_PGXS=1 install

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get remove -y build-essential postgresql-server-dev-15 git make gcc \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /pg_bigm

